# How to import a part by passing a parameter to exporter in MEF?

Tags: parameters, import, export, mef

Most of the time we import an export unconditionally.
I want to import some configurations. something like this:

```
[Import(typeof(System.Configuration.Configuration))]
private Configuration config
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

The problem is at export side I need to pass a parameter to get the right configuration. Here is the exported function:

```
[Export(typeof(System.Configuration.Configuration))]
private Configuration GetConfig(String name)
{
    // Load proper configuration and return it
}
```

My question is how to pass a parameter from import side, to the exported function. Note that I use exported function (which accept a parameter) inside the constructor of my importer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do, is use `Func<T, U>` and MEF will handle the delegate for you.  For instance:

```
public class FirstClass
{
  [Export("Method")]
  public string Method(string arg)
  {
    return arg.ToUpperInvariant();
  }
}

public class SecondClass
{
  [Import("Method")]
  public Func<string, string> Func;
}
```

In that example, I'm exporting a named contract and MEF will automatically determine how to wire up the target delegate for me.  I could have `Export`ed as `Func<string, string>` also.

So in your case, I would change your `Export` to:

```
[Export("GetConfiguration")]
```

And your `Import` and target property to:

```
[Import("GetConfiguration")]
public Func<string, Configuration> GetConfig { get; set; }
```

And the simply use the delegate to execute the imported function.

Hope that helps.